# List exists error when using stsadm -o import command

Tags: stsadm, list, error, import

When using the stsadm -o import command I am getting an error relating to a list already existing, the import then seems to fail. Should it not handle this scenario of a list already existing on the destination server?

I then used the UI to delete the existing list and ran the import again. It then seemed to fail at the same point saying the list exists. In the the UI the list appears but when I click it, reports that the list does not exist.

Can anyone suggest the best way to handle issues like this with the import command?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the -updateversions parameter? I've found that using this with the value of 2 helps.

Comment: Hi Lori - have you had a similar error with the import failing when a list already exists? It seems like what you suggest deletes, then creates, option 3 might be an option to ignore if exists. Thx!